# Understanding how "reorder" in R works

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the following data in `/tmp/thefile.csv` (a CSV file):

```
AA,12
AB,1
BA,2
```

and the following `R` code:

```
v = read.csv('/tmp/thefile.csv', header=F)
library('ggplot2')
v$V3 = reorder(v$V1, v$V2)
ggplot(v, aes(x=v$V3, y=v$V2), stat='identity') + geom_bar(fill='dark grey', stat="identity")
```

The plot shows the bars in ascending order, which is what I want. Without the `reorder` line, the plot appears in alphabetical order according to the factor.

However:

```
> v
  V1  V2  V3
1 AA  12  AA
2 AB   1  AB
3 BA   2  BA
```

shows that the order is still alphabetical. How is `ggplot` aware of the numerical order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `v$V3` you get the following (`print`) output:

```
[1] AA AB BA
attr(,"scores")
AA AB BA 
12  1  2 
Levels: AB BA AA
```

In the lowest line, you find the specified order of levels.

This infomation could be obtained more easily with the `levels` function:

```
levels(v$V3)
[1] "AB" "BA" "AA"
```

The function `reorder` does not change the values in the vector (or their order) but sets (changes) the `levels` and the `scores` attribute to indicate the order of factor levels:

```
attributes(v$V3)
$levels
[1] "AB" "BA" "AA"

$class
[1] "factor"

$scores
AA AB BA 
12  1  2
```