# Ggplot and reorder not working, even with stats::

Tags: r, ggplot2

I must be doing something stupid, but `reorder` in the `aes()` portion of ggplot periodically but inexplicably doesn't work for me.  Here are two versions of MWE that reproduce the problem on my system.  Neither one reorders the letters by the total.  The plot should show b, c, a on the X axis.

```
(df <- data.frame(letters = c("a", "b", "c"), nums = 1:3, total = c("150", "50", "100")))
reorder.plot <- ggplot(df, aes(reorder(letters, total), y = nums)) + 
  geom_point() 
reorder.plot

reorder.plot.stats <- ggplot(df, aes(stats::reorder(letters, total), y = nums)) + 
  geom_point() 
reorder.plot.stats
```

As can be seen, in the second example I specified the `stats` package.

One post said to reorder the data frame before calling ggplot, but I know reorder has worked in the past many times for me
[reorder data in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886472/reorder-data-in-ggplot)
Another question created a new, ordered variable and used that variable in ggplot.
[Understanding how "reorder" in R works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211872/understanding-how-reorder-in-r-works)

I am running under Windows 8 and have these packages loaded.  If this is relevant, how can I tell if reorder() is being masked, even when I specify `stats::`?

> search()  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886472/reorder-data-in-ggplot) ".GlobalEnv"               "package:extrafont"
>   "package:RCurl"            "package:bitops"            [5]
>   "package:qdap"             "package:qdapTools"
>   "package:qdapDictionaries" "package:XML"               [9]
>   "package:ReporteRs"        "package:ReporteRsjars"
>   "package:lubridate"        "package:gridExtra"        [13]
>   "package:RColorBrewer"     "package:dplyr"            "package:scales"
>   "package:Hmisc"            [17] "package:Formula"
>   "package:survival"         "package:splines"
>   "package:lattice"          [21] "package:grid"
>   "package:stringr"          "package:XLConnect"
>   "package:reshape2"         [25] "package:plyr"
>   "package:ggplot2"          "tools:rstudio"            "package:stats" 
>   [29] "package:graphics"         "package:grDevices"
>   "package:utils"            "package:datasets"         [33]
>   "package:methods"          "Autoloads"                "package:base"

Thank you, and I am already expressing my regret at not understanding the obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `total` column is a factor, but `reorder()` takes numerics or logicals. If you remove the quotes around `150, 50, 100` when you specify the `total` values, or if you convert `total` to a numeric first with `as.numeric()`, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You should always prefer to reorder your data, not your aesthetics. Reordering the `aes` only can have unexpected and unwanted results. Although it will often work after you play around with it, reordering the data itself should work straight off the bat:

```
df$letters <- reorder(df$letters, total)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to that of @Henry Brice above, but shows how to use a specific function to do the re-ordering.

I also came across this issue recently. My X variable was a factor. A boxplot I was using was working fine in sorting the boxplot items using the  method shown on P97 of the [Book by Wickham and Grolemund](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/exploratory-data-analysis.html), which is shown below.

In this example, the boxplot X-items ("class") are ordered using the median value of the "hwy" variable:

```
    ggplot(data = mpg) +
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x = reorder(class, hwy, FUN = median), y = hwy))
```

The above method stopped working for some new dataset and variable. I tried all sorts of things but the box-plots would not sort on the median.

I found the solution was to first add a new variable using mutate(), using the [method recommended here](https://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/resources/R/refactoring-levels.html). In the example below, the X variable "species" is   modified using mutate() and fct_reorder() with the ordering based on the median of the bill_length_mm variable.

```
    penguins %>% 
  mutate(species = fct_reorder(.f = species, .x = bill_length_mm, .fun = median, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = species, y = bill_length_mm)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

This worked to solve my problem. You can easily modify the above to order on other statistics such as the mean.

I hope that helps someone.